# Thread.join() does not work when executing the Thread by ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("program started");
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("thread finished");
            }
        });
        executor.execute(thread);
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("thread joined");

    }
```

When I start my **Thread** as showed above, `thread.join()` does not work and it does not wait for the Thread to be finished. I need to execute my **Thread** by a **ExecutorService** and also wait for that Thread to be finished. but my code does not work good. Can anyone help me?

Why I am not using **Future** instead of **Thread**?

because sometimes I need to interrupt my **Thread** and wait for that **Thread** to be finished. but when i cancel a **Future**, `future.get()` gets an Exception and does not wait for it's **Thread** to be finished.

I apologize in advance if the grammar of my sentence is not correct. because I can't speak English well.

Comment: `thread.join();` where is `thread` defined ?

Comment: Please only post compiling code snippets. After your edit `executor.execute(t);` doesn't work because `t` isn't defined.

Comment: @Hadi this code cannot not be compiled. There is no `thread` instance in your main method.

Comment: Executor execute() method only knows about Runnable and the methods defined in Runnable i.e. `run()`. There may be millions and millions of Programmers using the method. Any Programmer can pass any implementation of Runnable and can include any number of methods in the implementation. But each programmer will need to provide implementation of `run()` method as its defined in contract of Runnable. Now Executor execute() method only depends on the contract defined by Only Runnable and not on any particular implementation.

Comment: @GhostCat oh I did not realize :)... I meant a programmer may pass his implementation of Runnable interface but *should not* expect Executor execute method to know the specific implementation other than that run method exists in it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Simple answer: don't do that.

Do not mix layers of abstractions like this. The Executor interface doesn't `execute()` threads. It takes **Runnables**. It doesn't matter that you pass a Thread object to it, your thread will not be used at all, besides a call to the `run()` method.

Mixing "low layer" bare iron threads with an abstracted Executor service is simply a bad idea.

The whole point of that *thread pool* concept is that you do **not** try to control the underlying threads. There is simply no point in waiting for a pooled thread to *end*. A thread pool keeps threads around, because establishing threads is a (relatively) costly operations. So they don't end, but live on, to do *other* work in the future.

The real answer here: either don't use that executor service, or look for a solution that works with that concept (without you going in and doing low level stuff on the side).

And the "real real" answer: step back, and tell us about the "real" problem you intent to solve this way.

Comment: There used to be a feature in the JRE which caused a memory leak when Thread.run() was called without starting the thread itself. I thought it was a justified punishment for skipping the documentation. But the feature has been "removed" now.

Answer (score 8):

Your mistake is subtle.

Note the API of [Executor.execute()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html#execute-java.lang.Runnable-) : it takes a `Runnable`. And `Thread` implements `Runnable`, so it can be passed to the `Executor`. However, the implementation returned by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` only uses that `run()` method of the `Thread` instance you pass. The `Thread` itself is never started, as the executor uses the threads it manages internally in its thread pool.

The solution is simple : `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` retuns an `ExecutorService`, use its `submit(Runnable)` method instead. You'll get a `Future<?>` as a return value. Calling `get()` on the future will have the same effect as `Thread.join()`

For a more extensive explanation on how to use `ExecutorService`s you can look here : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html.

Comment: Honestly: it isn't a subtle mistake. It is more of a really strange idea.

Comment: @GhostCat I never said bug.

Comment: @GhostCat so you don't think it's subtle? Meh, that's an opinion, I guess. I've met senior programmers who've been scratching their heads for a while when making this very mistake.

Comment: I agree that the "act itself" of passing a thread object to something that expects Runnable is subtle. But the "basic idea" of passing a Thread to an Executor Service isn't subtle. Its as subtle as buying a baseball bat in order to drive a nail into the living room wall to mount a picture ....

Comment: @GhostCat bad example, because that might actually work ;) much like https://www.xkcd.com/2021/

Comment: @Hulk Of course. That is an essential part why I constructed the example that way. Thing is: "some solution is working" isn't the same as "it is a good, efficient solution". You might also be able to mount a picture when you only have a screw and a hammer (just takes a lot of force). A nail and a hammer are still the better solution.

Comment: In what way does calling `future.get()` "have the same effect as" `thread.join()`? I think what you are trying to say is that calling `future.get()` is the correct solution to the OP's problem or, that `future.get()` is the correct way to wait for a thread pool task to complete.

Comment: @jameslarge it has the same effect, in the sense that it blocks the current thread until the task finishes. As a bonus though, you're reusing the thread, and get feedback if an uncaught exception was thrown from the task.

Comment: Yeah, sure, but you're answering a question from somebody who doesn't understand the difference between a task and a thread... Doesn't even understand that there _is_ a difference. Instead of just tossing him a fish, you could spend just a few more keystrokes, and teach him how to catch fish.

Comment: @jameslarge I added a link :)

Answer (score 3):

When you use the `ExecutorService`, you should pass it a `Runnable`. A `Thread` is a `Runnable` but you're not using it as a thread if you pass it to an `ExecutorService`.

`ExecutorService` has another method, `submit`, that allows you to wait for the completion of a `Runnable` (or a `Callable`, if you want to return a result)

You can change your code to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("program started");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("thread finished");
        }
    };
    Future<?> future = executor.submit(runnable);
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("waited for completion");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The submited task will be executed as an `Runnable` object by the other thread. That's why the `join` will not block the main thread.

Your code is equivalent to:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("program started");
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("thread finished");
        }
    };

    executor.execute(runnable);

    try {
        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.join();  // the thread never start, so it will not block main thread
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("thread joined");
}
```

You can try to print the thread name:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread()); // Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("thread finished");
    }
});
executor.execute(thread);

System.out.println(thread); // Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Thread class extends Runnable Interface. So any method accepting Runnable type parameter will accept an instance of Thread (or any instance of a class implementing Runnable interface).
2. Executor.java (interface) has a method `execute(Runnable command)` An implementation provided by `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` uses its own separate internal Thread and starts the same. It uses the Runnable command passed in `execute(Runnable command)` method and executes the statements present in `run()` method.
3. You have provided an instance of Thread (which implements Runnable) hence the internal threads (as mentioned in point 2) invokes the run method but never invokes `start()` method on your Thread. `execute()` method accepts the instance you pass but **it only knows that it is of type Runnable, it does not know that method `start()` exists**. Without knowing it can not invoke it. Any other programmer could have passed an instance of a class like `class Task implements Runnable` and could have had methods like `invokeMeIAmImportantMethod()`. But any method that Executor would have known would have been only and only `public void run()` as defined in the contract of Runnable interface.
4. Method `join()` called on your Instance of Thread before `start()` will not make the current Thread wait for the completion of your Thread (your Thread never got Started).

A)  When we have used newCachedThreadPool() then it means we need a ThreadPool Service. It means Thread Pool Service will maange Threads and will execute your tasks (or commands). No point of starting your Thread to do a task and expecting a separte Threadpool also to be started. Its kind of mixed up ( little messed up) logic. 
So either remove Threadpool and just start your thread else remove your thread and just depend upon the Threadpool.

B)  Also I would recommend you to use debugging. You could have debugged and would have found the state of the Thread (it would have been NEW). This would have led you to research more and eventually you would have looked at the parameter expected by ExecutorService execute() method.